# VBScript to read specific line and extract characters and store it as a variable

Tags: variables, vbscript, character, extract, readline

I have a VB script that reads the 11th line from a text file. However from that line I need to extract characters 48 through 53 and save it as a variable. After this is accomplished I would like to use that variable and use it in a web url. Example below:

Contents of the szCPUSer.dat file look like this:
[image: szCPUSer.dat]

The script I have reads the 10th line

```
Const ForReading = 1

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("szCPUSer.dat", ForReading)

For i = 1 to 10
    objTextFile.ReadLine
Next

strLine = objTextFile.ReadLine
Wscript.Echo strLine

objTextFile.Close
```

I need the script to extract 03187 from the 11th line than store it as a variable SerNum. after this I would like to use that number extracted in a url for example:

http://seriallookup.com/serial=SerNum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works!

```
Const ForReading = 1
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("szCPUSer.dat", ForReading)
For i = 1 to 10
    objTextFile.ReadLine
Next
strLine = objTextFile.ReadLine
Wscript.Echo strLine
objTextFile.Close

'Gets 6 chars starting from Right side
SerNum = Right(strLine, 6)
'Gets 6 chars starting from Left side
SerNum = Left(SerNum, 5)
'Wscript.Echo SerNum
url = "http://seriallookup.com/serial=" & SerNum
Wscript.Echo url
```

Comment: I still have some issues when I added the last 2 lines at the end of the code shell.open "http://seriallookup.com/SerNum it fails and just posts the value SerNum instead of the variable value which would be 03187

Comment: I have modified the answer to give you the full working code. Also, you are reading the 11th line from the file, not 10th!

Comment: Thank you so much for you help on this issue. This really helps me understand the full pic. I did however add a few lines at the end of the script to launch the url instead of echo.                      'Option Explicit
Dim wsh
Set wsh=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wsh.Run "http://seriallookup.com/serial=" & SerNum

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at InStr function.  It lets you search for a substring.

http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_instr.asp

Then you can use the Right function to parse out the end bit of the line.

You can also look at the Split function so you can parse the lines into arrays and deal with it that way which would be best.

http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_split.asp