# need to check the version value in text file using vbscript

Tags: windows, vbscript, windows-scripting, wsh

I have a text file and just need to check version value mentioned in that text file. I have to grep version value (0.0.1) and check that value in VBScript `If` condition. If version is increased (0.0.2), next time script will need to check the new version. I usually do it in shell script, but I don't know how to do it in windows VBScript.

```
{
  "name": "iap",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "ignore": [
    "poc"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.2",
    "oclazyload": "~0.3",
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to match that particular line and extract the version information:

```
line = ...

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = """version"": ""(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)"""

Set m = re.Execute(line)
If m.Count = 1 Then
  version = m(0).SubMatches(0)
End If

WScript.Echo version
```

Comment: Thanks much..It works when we give the line value in the script. but I need to get the value from text file. I got it from the following link. Please take a look.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204268/vbscript-to-read-specific-line-and-extract-characters-and-store-it-as-a-variable

Comment: My answer was meant to explain how you extract the version number from a given line. I will not write the entire script for you.

Comment: Ok..fine Ansgar..Thanks a ton for your help :)